# Difference in handling onClicks with functions REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

What is the difference between these two lines:

```
<button onClick={() => this.updateTodoToShow("all")}>all</button>
```

and

```
<button onClick = {this.deleteCompleted}>delete completed</button>
```

Why is one called with an arrow function and not the other? When is it appropriate to do each of these? Here is the full code for those two functions:

```
deleteCompleted = () => {
          this.setState({
              todos: this.state.todos.filter(todo => !todo.complete)
          });
      };

updateTodoToShow = s => {
        this.setState({
          todoToShow: s
        });
      };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first uses an anonymous arrow function in order to pass a value other than the event to the function `updateTodoToShow`.

The second apparently does not need to pass anything besides the click event which is the default argument (in fact, it doesn't appear to use the event either), so it only passes the function reference to `this.deleteCompleted`.

If no extra parameter is needed for the event handler, passing only the function reference is better. Creating an unnecessary inline function is pointless, like in the following:

```js
onClick={(e) => this.handler(e)}
```

Is functionally equivalent to below, there is just no unnecessary in-between function:

```js
onClick={this.handler}
```

The main thing to understand here is that both methods are passing `onClick` a function reference. The first is passing a reference to the inline function, the second is passing a reference to the `deleteCompleted` function.

It is appropriate to use the inline function **only** when you need to add extra arguments to the handler. Another common usecase would be passing an `id` or other identifier when creating buttons in a loop.